# Two Factor Authentication without login flows,Authenticate app and free of cost

Tags: community, force.com, security, salesforce-id

Hi I have to know is there is any Two Factor Authentication approach for sales force,which doesn't contains any login flows,Authentication app and with free of cost for third party applications like auth0,duo(but these are not free) . Please let me know if there is any approaches ?
I have tried with login flows, sales force authentication app in mobile and with licensed web apps (not free of cost)  like auth0,Okta,Duo Security etc..

Comment: What is stopping you from not using salesfore authenticator app ? It comes for free ?

Comment: Hi Mohith
Thank you for spending your valuable time for my question,But every customer doesn't have android or ios mobiles ,some customers login to web and they will get OTP through their small mobiles.